# How to get the current appName from the Navigation Bar

Tags: lightning-apps

I need to get the current appName and based on this my controller params will change, Im working in a VF Page that is displayed from a VF Tab in LEX.

I have tried using:

1. `getElementsByClassName` but its undefined since its not a lightning component
2. `Schema.DescribeTabSetResult` `tsr.isSelected()` returns `SF Classic app` (weird)
3. Looking directly for the std component without luck

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the app name for the current user in your Apex controller.

```
public static String getAppName() {
    UserAppInfo userAppInfo = [SELECT Id, AppDefinitionId FROM UserAppInfo WHERE UserId = :UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1];
    AppDefinition appDefinition = [SELECT DurableId, Label FROM AppDefinition Where DurableId = :userAppInfo.AppDefinitionId LIMIT 1];
    return appDefinition.Label;
}
```